# Is there a way to render animated transparent gif on canvas and change the delay between frames

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, gif, transparent

I am developing a website where it's possible to provide a link to a transparent animated gif (often from giphy) and I want to render it (animated) on a canvas while keeping the transparency of the animated gif. This to be able to change the animation speed of the GIF.

I've tried using the following

- `fastgif` but only one out of thirty frames shows an image, the rest are completely transparent. Gifs without transparency works.
- `gifuct-js` but the background is black and not transparent. I understood that gifuct provides a transparencyIndex but it doesn't show up when decoding the gif.

I've tried many different gifs, including ones that are not from giphy created with Photoshop and After Effects but to no result.

---

fastgif (where `all` is the decoded gif fetched with `fetch`)

```
import { Decoder } from 'fastgif'
const d = new Decoder()
window.fetch('https://media.giphy.com/media/tTutsU63rnHC8/giphy.gif')
  .then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then((buffer) => d.decode(buffer))
  .then(async (frames) => {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = all[0].imageData.width;
  canvas.height = all[0].imageData.height;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  let frame = 0;
  while (true) {
    ctx.putImageData(all[frame].imageData, 0, 0);
    await new Promise((resolve) => window.setTimeout(resolve, all[frame].delay));
    if (++frame === all.length) {
      frame = 0;
    }
  }
})
```

---

gifuct-js
This one I only tried rendering one frame to see if the transparency worked, but the background was all black and no transparency whatsoever.

```
var tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas')
var tempContext = tempCanvas.getContext('2d')

window.fetch('https://media.giphy.com/media/tTutsU63rnHC8/giphy.gif')
  .then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then((buffer) => new GIF(buffer))
  .then((gif) => gif.decompressFrames(true))
  .then(async (frames) => {
    const frame = frames[0]
    const dims = frame.dims
    c.width = dims.width
    c.height = dims.height
    tempCanvas.width = dims.width
    tempCanvas.height = dims.height
    const imageData = tempContext.createImageData(dims.width, dims.height)
    tempContext.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0)
    // set the patch data as an override
    imageData.data.set(frame.patch)
    let pix = imageData.data
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height)
    ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0)
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0)
    image.src = tempCanvas.toDataURL('image/png')
  })
```

---

I expect the render to look like if an `<img src='https://media.giphy.com/media/tTutsU63rnHC8/giphy.gif' />` was added to a website. Animated with transparent background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution I found that involves gifler and konvajs:
https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/GIF_On_Canvas.html.

**Update** Here's a solution that includes the need for adjusting the delay (note the comment within the `onDrawFrame` function.

```js
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: width,
  height: height,
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
// use external library to parse and draw gif animation
function onDrawFrame(ctx, frame) {
  /*
    Here is where you can adust the delay between frames.
  */
  frame.delay = 80;
  // update canvas that we are using for Konva.Image
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(frame.buffer, frame.x, frame.y);
  // redraw the layer
  layer.draw();
}

gifler('https://media1.giphy.com/media/l4pTpdRiFv10jFlNC/200w_d.gif').frames(canvas, onDrawFrame, true);
// draw resulted canvas into the stage as Konva.Image
var image = new Konva.Image({
  image: canvas
});
layer.add(image);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@3.4.1/konva.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/gifler@0.1.0/gifler.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works great for rendering the transparent GIF, thank you. But I can't find a way to change the delay between each frame for gifler. Any ideas? I've tried using the `get()` to get the full animator, but lack of documentation gets me nowhere.

Comment: @Victor I made some adjustments that show how to add delay.